# Will old user accounts be merged with SE 2.0 accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I think several people had SE1.0 chiphacker accounts and SE2.0 accounts.  Will they be merged?  What if they were not merged?

My chiphacker account and SE2.0 account used the same openid, but they did not automatically merge.

On SE1.0, I think an admin of some sort just merged them by hand.  How does this work in SE2.0?

Comment: mine got merged today, maybe becuase I wrote an email to stack exchange. But they took all my badges and halved my reputation points.

Comment: @Rick - There was a rep recalculation: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4/5#5  Also, your badges are still present on the parent site, but you have to re-earn them on Meta

Comment: I also wrote to team (at) stackexchange.com and Jeff very kindly merged the accounts.  I didn't ask until this afternoon, and they were merged this evening; even with resources stretched thin, they are doing a very nice job with the fairly large merger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes, they will require a merge, and yes, they are being merged.

**Long answer:** For a brief interval, I had also had two accounts: my old Chiphacker mod/user account, as well as an Area51 account, so I merged the two.  There weren't any other dupes that I noticed at the time, because the duplicate account isn't created until you log in with the 2.0 account (We might be dealing with this for some time), and I did this within a few minutes after the site opened.  Ideally, this would become an automated thing (if it's not already).

Yes, it can and will be done.  However, mod resources are stretched right now.  On both SE 1.0 and SE 2.0, moderators and administrators can merge accounts.  On Chiphacker, everyone with over 2.5k rep was a moderator, along with a few other notable contributors, plus the admins littlebirdceo and mad_z, so things happened pretty fast.

Now, reputation gets you the privileges [described here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), the highest of which is a subset of the privileges afforded to a moderator. The privileges afforded to a user with 2,000 rep described in the link consist of everything listed there, the right to see (and undelete) deleted posts, as well as access to these moderation tools (lists of ___):

- posts flagged as offensive or spam
- recently deleted posts
- recently closed questions
- see all recent edits in chronological order
- new posts by new users
- questions with newly created tags
- new answers to old questions
- recent questions with most view velocity
- recent questions with most edit velocity
- recent questions with most vote velocity

Everything else has to be taken care of by someone from Stack Overflow Internet Services, inc.  At the present time, that includes Jarrod Dixon, Jeff Atwood, Jin, David Fullerton, Geoff Dalgas, and Robert Cartaino (Denoted by a ♦ by their username).  In the future, we can elect moderators from our own ranks.